# Translate Sass to Css in browser

Tags: javascript, css, coffeescript, sass

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a SASS.js? Something like LESS.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4436643/is-there-a-sass-js-something-like-less-js)

I'd like to build prototyping html page that allows editing code, just like jsfiddle or jsbin. And I don't want to run any conversions on server side, because prototyping means quickly hacking something together, with no network dependency: think of typing on your iPad while sitting on a bus in Siberia with no network for 100 km in any direction and with wild bears around.

To convert coffeescript to js there is coffeescript compiler that runs right in browser, so I can write type="text/coffeescript" and forget about conversion until deployment.

Is there similar tool for Sass to support type="text/sass" or am I stuck with Css?

Comment: I haven't found any JS SASS implementations. Only LESS.

Comment: Is there something wrong with just using the watch command to continuously recompile the Sass files or does iPad not have access to the terminal?  I use Virtual Box to contain my development server on my Windows laptop, so I don't see why network connectivity (or lack of) is even an issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See here: [Is there a SASS.js? Something like LESS.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4436643/is-there-a-sass-js-something-like-less-js)

In short, there is a CommonJS module for it (designed for node) that you might be able to use, with minor modification, alongside something like curl.js or other script loaders.