# Browser SCSS processor?

Tags: css, less, sass

I have a develop where I can't install anything (it's a long story). I need to develop just with plain HTML / Browser JS and I want to use a CSS preprocessor. I like SCSS (SASS) but in order to use it I have to install ruby on my machine, execute it's program and listen the filesystem...

Is there just a Browser JS file than I could include on my page and load unprocessed SCSS?

I've seen [is-there-a-sass-js-something-like-less-js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4436643/is-there-a-sass-js-something-like-less-js) but answers are focused on production state:

1. Why should you make all your users compile your stylesheets when you can do it once for all of them.
2. What would your site look like if javascript is disabled.
3. If you decide to change to a server-side implementation at a future time, all your templates must be changed accordingly.

But I think it's a different question because I don't want this to production server, I want this to develop with SCSS and when the page is done I can connect to a external machine, process the SCSS and upload it to the production server. But I can't do this for every change I do while developing!!!

Comment: It's a bit confusing what you actually want. Less & as far as i'm aware Sass, allow you to either compile locally into a post-proccessed css file or compile on the fly client side when you files are loaded to production.

Comment: @Rhyso - He wants to be able to code in SCSS and compile it without installing anything. Basically, probably a web-based SCSS compiler.

Comment: Exactly, LESS for example has LESS.js, a script to embed on a web page than will process every LESS stylesheet

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a SASS.js? Something like LESS.js?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4436643/is-there-a-sass-js-something-like-less-js)

Comment: @A.MatíasQuezada: Maybe the answers on that other question didn't cover what you're looking for simply because it doesn't exists. I suggest you close this question and start a bounty on the other one.

Comment: @A.MatíasQuezada If you're not allowed to install on your work machine, ask for a proper development server (no one in their right mind would deny this):  either a Virtual Box or a physical machine that's almost identical to your production server.  Using an FTP-able editor (or mounting the Virtual Box as a network drive), it feels just like working local.

Comment: Is a PHP compiler an option? http://www.phpsass.com/

Comment: well, i didnt thought about a php compiler, but in my casd ti will be valid since the server logi is in php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there just a Browser JS file than I could include on my page and
>   load unprocessed SCSS?

I don't think so. I've tried pretty much all the CSS preprocessors out there, and the only one I know that works in the browser is LESS.

There are a couple of Win/Mac/Air/Node apps to pre-process different standards while on dev tho:

- http://winless.org/
- http://crunchapp.net/
- http://compass.handlino.com/
- http://wearekiss.com/simpless
- http://drzaus.com/plugins/sassifier-followup-make-sass-compiler-its-own-plugin

Comment: Thank you so much for the info, I will take a look to this tools

Comment: [sass.js](https://github.com/medialize/sass.js/) should do what you're (OP is) looking for