# How to use sass/scss file in my HTML project?

Tags: css, sass

I am new to sass/scss and want to know how I can use sass file in my HTML project?

Do I have to first compile it into CSS with command line or anything else that compiles scss/sass runtime into css file at a time when webpage loads into browser?

So any help?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a SASS.js? Something like LESS.js?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4436643/is-there-a-sass-js-something-like-less-js)

Comment: There are a few settings involved, but usually you just set it up so that it compiles to CSS every time you save changes to the SCSS file. This is too broad to explain here. There are tutorials online.

Comment: Do u mean I have to use code like sass --watch app/sass:public/stylesheets ?

Answer (score 1):

There are many options to create a Project working with SASS, but the most common is using **Compass**, I see you're new to it, I strongly recommend you read a [Tutorial](http://thesassway.com/beginner/getting-started-with-sass-and-compass) about **Compass**, after understanding this you should look others options to use the same SASS like working with `gulp`, `gulp-sass`, `node-sass`, `browser-sync`, and many other options to use the same Tool.